# trouble inserting data into sqlite with knexjs

Tags: javascript, sqlite, knex.js

I am currently using knexjs to insert data into sqlite, but I have stumbled upon an odd issue.

This code inserts data successfully:

```
knex.insert({"request":requestquery,"date":date}).into("requests")
            .then(function (id) {});
```

But this code does not insert data and fails silently:

```
knex.insert({"request":requestquery,"date":date}).into("requests")
```

Why is the `then` code important? Why is it necessary to insert data?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not calling `then()`, you still have query builder, which can still be modified.

```
var q = knex("requests");
q.toString(); 
// 'select * from "requests"

q.where('id', 1).toString(); 
// 'select * from "requests" where "id" = 1'

q.orderBy('bar').toString(); 
// 'select * from "requests" where "id" = 1 order by "bar" asc'

// now query is actually executed and converted to promise 
var promise = q.then(res => console.log('got', res));
```

So query builder is something that Promise A+ spec calls thenable. It can be used to build query piece by piece and the query being built is not triggered until user wants to trigger it.

One thing that is nice about thenables is that if you return them from promise, their `.then()` function will be called and query will be triggered.

So this works without calling then to inner query:

```
knex('mydata').then(() => {
  return knex('otherdata'); // no need to call .then here
}).then(otherDataResults => {
  console.log(otherDataResults);
});
```